# Handling token with Grails 3

Tags: java, spring, http, grails, http-headers

I am trying to connect to an API  using Grails 3.1.4.

In fact the authentication is done and I getthe generated token after sending email and password.

I am trying to send queries after that. However, I can't send the token in header of the http query

```
String url="www.myurl.com"
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL))

connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection()
connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
connection.setDoOutput(true)
connection.setDoInput(true)
connection.setConnectTimeout(10000)
connection.setRequestProperty("content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
connection.setRequestProperty("Set-Cookie","token/"+token)
OutputStream output = connection?.getOutputStream()
output.write(query.getBytes())
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the authentication mechanism used. If JWT tokens are used, you need to add a http header with the keyword "Authentication" and a value of "Bearer ". Please ask your service supplier which mechanism is used. Usually a 401 statuscode is an indication you are doing something wrong.

Comment: In fact  ,I am using REST web service , it is a Cookie-based Authentication  for spring. I think the problem is in this section ' connection.setRequestProperty("Set-Cookie","JSESSIONID="+token+"; Path=/; HttpOnly")`